# Populate a table full of TextViews with data from Parse.com database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a table in Parse with 4 columns (except the built-in columns).

I want to get these 4 columns and arrange this data in a table, inside TextViews.

Each table row on my app needs to contain different data. How can I create this table and arrange the data in this table?

I already know pretty much how to create a table. the important is to fill the table with the data from Parse.com table.

**EDIT #1:**

I don't know how many rows there are in the database, so the table needs to be endless

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have a row layout defined like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

After that, now i would use a single RecyclerView to inflate and populate that Data from your Database. With some Gaps in the code it should look somewhat like this.

```
    public void doStuff() {
        RecyclerView rv = findViewById();

        TableAdapter ta = new TableAdapter();

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
             public void done(List<Data> content, ParseException pEx) {
                ta.setData(content);
             }
        }
        rv.setAdapter(ta);

    }

    public class TableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RowHolder> {

        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

        public void setData(List<Data> newData){
            data.clear();
            data.addAll(newData);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public RowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new RowHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tablerow, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RowHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(data.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }
    }

    public class RowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;

        public RowHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
            tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
            tv3 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item3);
            tv4 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item4);
        }

        public void bind(Data d) {
            tv1.setText(d.field1);
            tv2.setText(d.field2);
            tv3.setText(d.field3);
            tv4.setText(d.field4);
        }
    }

    class Data {
        String field1, field2, field3, field4;
    }
```

Comment: row? a row would typically indicate a single item. Each item would have its own row in the RecyclerView. It doesnt matter how many Elements are in that List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>(); List. It will just add every Element in the List to the RecyclerView, as you scroll through. If you dont know how many columns there are in your Database, that sounds like a design issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The important is to fill the table with the data from Parse.com table

This is how you query data from [Parse: Retrieving Objects](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-retrieving-objects)

**Example:**

```
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Deals");    
    query.whereEqualTo("Brand", "Burnettes");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects,
                ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("Brand", "Retrieved " + objects.size() + " Brands");
                for (ParseObject dealsObject : objects) {
                   // use dealsObject.get('columnName') to access the properties of the Deals object.
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Brand", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }    
        }
    });
```

As you are populating data from database, you don't need to hard code Rows and Columns because you don't know rows in database. **The solution is to create layout dynamically**:

```
TableLayout table_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout....);

    table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout);

}

public void buildRow (Object obj){

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.addView(tv1);

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.addView(tv2);

    TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.addView(tv3);

    TextView tv4 = new TextView(this);
    tv4.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.addView(tv4);

    // Populate each textview with obj values

    table_layout.addView(row);

}
```

Call `buildRow(...)` for every object you obtain from `Parse`

Comment: @IdoNaveh My answer is for any number of rows.